# Complex Analysis Inequalities:$\lvert\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\rvert \le \frac{1}{R^2-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

The Problem gave me that: $$f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}$$
and it wants me to prove that when let $$z=Re^{i\theta}$$ 
where $$R>1 , 0 \le \theta \le \pi$$
the following will be true. $$\lvert{f(z)}\rvert \le \frac{1}{R^2-1}$$

I have no idea what should be used here.

Comment: Please don't use the `proof-verification` tag in cases in which you did not attempt to provide a proof.

Comment: then now your estimate make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, $~~R>1$ then you have,

$$0<R^2 -1 = ||z^2|- 1| \le |z^2 +1|\implies \frac{1}{|z^2+1|}\le \frac{1}{R^2-1}$$

Hence, $$ |f(z)|=\frac{|z|}{|z^2 +1|} \le  \frac{e^{-R\sin\theta}}{R^2-1}  \le  \frac{1}{R^2-1}$$

Given that
$$|e^{iz}| = |e^{i(R\cos\theta+iR\sin\theta)}| = \color{blue}{|e^{-Rsin\theta}e^{iR\cos\theta}|=e^{-Rsin\theta}\le 1}$$

Because, $0\le\theta\le\pi$ we have $1\ge \sin \theta\ge 0$ which implies $e^{-Rsin\theta}\le 1$.

Comment: I type it wrong, sorry. I've edited it

Comment: But still your numerator estimate is wrong

Comment: so it must state that R>1?

Comment: Where does $\theta$ sit?.

Comment: @RexSolus see the edit  now it should be fine